# Usleep breaks an holded key in ncurses for movement

Tags: c++, ncurses

I am programming a bomberman game in ncurses and I got a trouble.

I want to give player a capability of hold key to constant move.

It works fine in non blocking mode of getch(), but only until I implement a waiting in game loop.

```
    struct timeval start, end;
long mtime, seconds, useconds;    
long frame = 5000; /* usec */
while ( m_state == STATE_PLAYING ) {
    /* tick driving */
    gettimeofday(&start, NULL);
    Tick();
    Draw();

    gettimeofday(&end, NULL);

    seconds  = end.tv_sec  - start.tv_sec;
    useconds = end.tv_usec - start.tv_usec;
    mtime = ((seconds) * (1000 * 1000) + useconds ) + 500;

    if(tickdriven) usleep( frame - mtime );
}
```

In tick I load keys and then process them. But if I set tickdriven to true, it brokes a hold key functionality :( suddenly I has to press the key again to keep moving. So my question is: Why uspeep brokes an hold key functionality, and how can I repair it? :(

Comment: Which function are you using to do non-blocking mode?

Comment: I use nodelay(stdscr, TRUE);

Comment: Try timeout(0) instead